# JQuery Tabs Stop Working

Tags: jquery, html

What is wrong with this? It worked fine but all of a sudden it broke. Whenever I click on the dropup options, the tabs do not change as suppose to. I went through the code to find if there was any syntax errors but none that I could find. Please advise:

JavaScript:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .dropdown-menu a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-6">

    <div class="tabs">

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <p><h3 class="text-center"><b>Test</b></h3></p>
            <p><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/assets/image.jpg"/></p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p><h3 class="text-center"><b>Test</b></h3></p>
          <p><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/assets/image.jpg"/></p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab3" class="tab">
            <p><h3 class="text-center"><b>Test</b></h3></p>
            <p><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/assets/image.jpg"/></p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab4" class="tab">
            <p><h3 class="text-center"><b>Test</b></h3></p>
            <p><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/assets/image.jpg"/></p>
        </div>

        <div id="tab5" class="tab">
            <p><h3 class="text-center"><b>Test</b></h3></p>
            <p><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/assets/image.jpg"/></p>
        </div>
 <div id="tab6" class="tab">
            <p><h3 class="text-center"><b>Test</b></h3></p>
            <p><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/assets/image.jpg"/></p>
        </div>
 <div id="tab7" class="tab">
            <p><h3 class="text-center"><b>Test</b></h3></p>
            <p><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/assets/image.jpg"/></p>
        </div>
 <div id="tab8" class="tab">
            <p><h3 class="text-center"><b>Test</b></h3></p>
            <p><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/assets/image.jpg"/></p>
        </div>
</div>

<p><h2 class="text-center">Some Text</h2></p>
<div class="dropup text-center">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle text-center" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Choose One
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu text-center" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li class="text-center"><a href="#tab1">ASI</a></li>
        <li class="text-center"><a href="#tab2">Test</a></li>
        <li class="text-center"><a href="#tab3">Test</a></li>
        <li class="text-center"><a href="#tab4">Test</a></li>
        <li class="text-center"><a href="#tab5">Test</a></li>
        <li class="text-center"><a href="#tab6">Test</a></li>
        <li class="text-center"><a href="#tab7">Test</a></li>
        <li class="text-center"><a href="#tab8">Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Based On: [jQuery Tabs](http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the `jquery tab` initialization on `document.ready`.

```
 $(".tabs").tabs();
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/p12qvon2/

Comment: In the jsfiddle example it works with the initialization above but when I add that code to my site it does not. This is weird..

Comment: you are probably missing references to jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js

Comment: This is in my head tag..   <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/libs/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/libs/slider.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/libs/jquery-ui.js"></script> I just find it very weird that it worked then it doesn't..